# Typescript syntax for a function returning observable or multiple type

Tags: typescript, types, syntax

I have a function that returns an observable of all widgets. There a 2 types of widgets. Here's what I've tried and the IDE doesn't complain, but my compiler does:

```
public getAllWidgets(): Observable<WidgetType1 | WidgetType2> {
...
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to know what the compiler complains about. What's the error you get?

Comment: I got it. It was returning an array
Observable<WidgetType1[] | WidgetType2[]> was failing too because 1 property of the object was not required. Making it optional fixed it, which I don't know why but then
 Observable<(WidgetType1 | WidgetType2)[]> made it all work.

Answer (score 1):

Observable<(WidgetType1 | WidgetType2)[]>

An array was being returned. The error wasn't clear on that.