# How can I provide multiple return type with async function

Tags: typescript

My current function can return string or custom type as implemented

```
   public getTenantsByEmail = (emailId: string): Promise<ITenants | string | IErrorResponse> => {
    if (emailId) {
        this.config = GetConfig();
        if (this.config.isMock) {
            return this.mock();
        } else {
            return getAxios.get(`tenants/emails/${emailId}`)
                .then((response: IHttpResponse) => response.data);
        }
    } else {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('Invalid Email id'));
    }
```

}

but when I am using this

```
return tenantRegistration.createTenant(postObject)
    .then((response: ITenants) => {
        expect(response.result.bucket).toBe('my-cool-bucket');
    });
```

I am getting this error

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(response: ITenants) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string | ITenants | IErrorResponse) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.
```

Types of parameters 'response' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | ITenants | IErrorResponse' is not assignable to type 'ITenants'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ITenants'.

How can I use this with multiple return types ?

Comment: I believe this question has been answered before. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242426/typescript-multiple-return-types-with-identical-parameters)

Comment: can you please explain a bit? this does not answer my question

Comment: I don't get it... does `createTenant()` have anything to do with `getTenantsByEmail()`?  Is that a typo or does this just not constitute a [mcve]?  And assuming `createTenant()` returns the same sort of promise as `getTenantsByEmail()`, then the error is a good error... it's saying you are not checking inside your callback whether `response` is a `string` or an `IErrorResponse`... you just *assume* it's an `ITenants`, but you should be checking it, not assuming it.  Please try to modify the code here to constitute something reproducible in a standalone environment, so we can help.  Good luck!